# Conditional block is not working in cruise control

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I am using following code in my ccnet.config file

```
<tasks>
  <conditional>
    <conditions>
      <compareCondition>
        <value1>${Target1}</value1>
        <value2>D:\QAT_Publish</value2>
        <evaluation>equal</evaluation>
      </compareCondition>
    </conditions>
    <tasks>         
      <buildpublisher>
        <sourceDir>D:\QATV2Demo</sourceDir>
        <publishDir>D:\QAT_Publish</publishDir>
        <useLabelSubDirectory>true</useLabelSubDirectory>
      </buildpublisher>
           </tasks>
    <elseTasks>

        <buildpublisher>
          <sourceDir>D:\QATV2Demo</sourceDir>
          <publishDir>D:\QAT_Publish1</publishDir>
          <useLabelSubDirectory>true</useLabelSubDirectory>
        </buildpublisher>

    </elseTasks>
  </conditional>
<tasks>
```

But this hole block is not executing at all.

Please tell what mistake i am doing here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have not seen true.

Please try it and let me know if there are any more quires.

Comment: Please could you explain your answer? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your conditional be:

```
<compareCondition>
     <value1>$(Target1)</value1>
     <value2>D:\QAT_Publish</value2>
     <evaluation>equal</evaluation>
</compareCondition>
```

? Using curly braces for variables is a NAnt construct - CC.NET usually uses round brackets.